# AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: handler (func) is required in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongooose to connect mongodb but i am getting following error

```
/Users/uchitkumar/api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:804
          throw err;
          ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: handler (func) is required
    at new AssertionError (internal/errors.js:315:11)
    at _toss (/Users/uchitkumar/api/node_modules/assert-plus/assert.js:22:11)
    at Function.out.(anonymous function) [as func] (/Users/uchitkumar/api/node_modules/assert-plus/assert.js:122:17)
    at process (/Users/uchitkumar/api/node_modules/restify/lib/server.js:1352:20)
    at argumentsToChain (/Users/uchitkumar/api/node_modules/restify/lib/server.js:1361:12)
    at Server.serverMethod [as put] (/Users/uchitkumar/api/node_modules/restify/lib/server.js:1475:21)
```

my code for connection is as follow

```
server.listen(config.port, function() {

    mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('Mongoose default connection error: ' + err)
        process.exit(1)
    })

    mongoose.connection.on('open', function(err) {

        if (err) {
            console.log('Mongoose default connection error: ' + err)
            process.exit(1)
        }

        console.log(
            '%s v%s ready to accept connections on port %s in %s environment.',
            server.name,
            config.version,
            config.port,
            config.env
        )

        require('./routes')

    })

    global.db = mongoose.connect(config.db.uri)

})
```

routes code

```
server.get('/', function indexHTML(req, res, next) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../index.html', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
            return;
        }

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
        next();
    });
});
```

This was fine ... I changed something and now it stopped working with this error. The error is that it is not able to assert some function... in mongodb client. it needed a function. Is it asking to add some handler function? where to add that
Thank in advance

Comment: `config.db.uri`? What's the value of that? Also if you think you are using `global.db` anywhere, then it does not actually contain what you seem to think it does.

Comment: @NeilLunn db: {
        uri: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/api',
    },

Comment: is that the value of `console.log(config.db.uri)`? Or `console.log(config)`?

Comment: its value of config

Comment: @NeilLunn and i am not using global.db anywhere... even after starting connection without that assignment I am getting the same error

Comment: No `err` ever gets passed to the `open` handler so that's useless code there. You're using mongoose, so where are your models? Bottom line is "changed something" without actually stating what that change was is not helping you here. The base logic is reversed anyhow since the `http` listen "should" be inside the database connection callback, and not the other way around as you have it

Comment: Write yourself a small script to simply connect, then use a model. And keep progressively adding things like they are in your main code as steps to identify. It's not asking you to "add a handler", but rather you're passing something invalid in somewhere. Where that "somewhere" is cannot be determined without seeing the full picture.

Comment: ok I will try above suggestions .. thanks

Answer (score 3):

`handler (func) is required` is an error that is thrown by restify if one of your routes or middlewares is undefined.

For example:

```
server.put('/foo/');
```

This would also trigger it:

```js
var myMidelware = undefined; // todo: define this

app.put('/route', myMiddleware, (req, res) => { /* todo: handle req */ })
```

That will throw the error `handler (func) is required` when it tries to validate that `myMidelware` is a function.

I don't see that in your posted routes code, but I think it's happening somehow. Do you have a PUT method defined somewhere?

(The same error would also happen with server.get(), server.post(), etc, but the `[as put]` in the stack trace indicates that it's choking on a server.put() call.)

See https://github.com/restify/node-restify/blob/v7.2.1/lib/server.js#L1386

Also, I don't believe the error has anything to do with mongodb; mongo is just in the stack because you run `require('./routes')` in the mongo connection open handler. The error is coming from your routes file. Annoyingly, mongo's error handling is loosing part of the stack trace. If you moved `require('./routes')` to outside of the mongo stuff, it would give you the proper stack trace.